# modular group, prime ideals

Tags: maximal-and-prime-ideals, modular-function, modular-group

I'm probably in over my head, but I came across the following sentence in [a thesis](https://scholar.colorado.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2430&context=honr_theses) by Evan Oliver entitled "Congruence Subarrangements of the Schmidt Arrangement":

"The modular group is the set of all matrices in P SL2(Z) whose elements reduce component-wise to the identity matrix over a prime ideal."

I know what a prime ideal is, and I have a basic understanding of the modular group, but the sentence above confounds me. His statement comes from a definition of PSL(2,Z) whereby

a ≡ d ≡ 1 (mod p) and b ≡ c ≡ 0 (mod p).

but that is not a definition of PSL(2,Z) that I'm familiar with. Is it related to the unit determinant?

Comment: According to Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_group#Definition), the modular group "is isomorphic to the projective special linear group $PSL(2, \Bbb{Z})$"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_group#Congruence_subgroups) under "Congruence Subgroups". Basically, when he talks about the "Modular Group" he is actually talking about $\Gamma(p)$, which is the kernel of the natural homomorphism $\phi_{p}: \mathrm{PSL}(2,\mathbb{Z}) \to \mathrm{PSL}(2,\mathbb{Z}_{p})$ (for some prime $p$).

Wikipedia is using the non-projective version of the group, so they mention that $\Gamma(N)$ is the set of matrices with $a \equiv d \equiv \pm 1 \bmod{N}$ and $b \equiv c \equiv 0$. But when we are working projectively, we can always scale the matrix so that $a \equiv d \equiv 1$.

(The more I read the Wikipedia article, the less I like it because $-I$ is **not** in the kernel when considering $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z}) \to \mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z}_{p})$ by reduction $\bmod{p}$, but this problem goes away when you consider the projective groups.)